# Change website design for mobile devices or browser resize

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

Im sorry if this has been asked before im sure somewhere there must be an answer for this but for some or other reason I cant find it, probably using wrong search query

I know you can use media queries to target different devices like so:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    div#wrapper {
        width: 400px;
    }
}
```

But what I would like to know is, how to change my websites design based on device it is viewed on?

**Example**

Lets say my normal site structure is like this:

**if desktop**

```
<div id="user">
    <div id="profilePic">
        <img src="images/responSiveTest/ppic.PNG" class="p-img" />
    </div>
    <div id="uname">
        <h4 style="color:white">Welcome  Guest</h4>
        <p style="color:white">Please Log in</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now when user views my site on a mobile device how do I change my `div` / site layout, lets say to something different like this

**if Mobile device**

```
<div id="mobileNav">
    <div id="namePic">
        <!-- Mobile user -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope what im asking makes sense, thanks to everyone on this amazing site for helping

Comment: I understand this is old but for others seeing this: Consider just hiding non-critical "visual" parts to get everything to fit. Changing the markup normally means changing the functionality and that is not a good experience for the end user. Too many times I have been to "mobile" versions of sites that are unusable because basic actions don't match the desktop versions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I usually do this in my projects. I prepare content by default but its set to display: none, when media query detects the mobile device width it will render appropriate content for the device.

with CSS Media Query

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="desktop">
        <!--
            some content and markups here. by default this is loaded in desktop
        -->
    </div>

    <div class="mobile_device_380px">
        <!-- content and some markups for mobile -->
    </div>

    <div class="mobile_device_480px">
        <!-- content and some markups for mobile -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
  /* if desktop */
    .mobile_device_380px {
        display: none;
    }
    .mobile_device_480px {
        display: none;
    }


    /* if mobile device max width 380px */
    @media only screen and (max-device-width: 380px) {
        .mobile_device_380px{display: block;}       
        .desktop {display: none;}
    } 

    /* if mobile device max width 480px */
    @media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
       .mobile_device_480px{display: block;}
       .desktop {display: none;}
    }
```

*Take note your page might take long to load. just limit what you need to change and be specific.*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with pure JavaScript, here it is-

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
// some code.. 
}
```

Again you can do this with jquery-

```
$.browser.device = (/android|webos|iphone|ipad|ipod|blackberry|iemobile|opera mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));
```

If you want to do this with PHP the [check out this article](http://mobiforge.mobi/design-development/lightweight-device-detection-php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this module](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect)

To detect a mobile device such as phone or tablet you can use this code.

```
require_once '../Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;
$deviceType = ($detect->isMobile() ? ($detect->isTablet() ? 'tablet' : 'phone') : 'computer');
```